# Swift WatchKit : startUpdatingLocation() is unavailable

Tags: swift, watchkit, core-location, cllocationmanager, watchos-2

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

I am using this same code in the iphone app and I wanted to try for watch os, but I took an error : "startUpdatingLocation() is unavailable". I need this function to start to get location and datas. What is the problem? I can't figured it out.

Comment: You cant use location with watchkit

Comment: incorrect @GeneratorOfOne

Comment: Ok, I thought that the whole framework is not available for watch os. That is great indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually CLLocationManager ***is*** available in WatchKit.

Just not `startUpdatingLocation()`.

Here's the documentation at [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestLocation).  Notice that `startUpdatingLocation` is referenced, but is grayed out and isn't actually defined on that documentation page.  All you can do is call a one time `requestLocation()`.

And to be more formal, in the CLLocationManager.h header file, you'll see the declaration:

```
- (void)startUpdatingLocation __TVOS_PROHIBITED __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: yeah I imported the CoreLocation, but not using startUpdatingLocation(). What should I do instead of startUpdatingLocation() ?

Comment: I think you can do a one time `requestLocation()` when you want to display something.

Comment: I tried the requestLocation and it gives an uncaught exception : "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:'"

Comment: so declare your view controller (or some object) as a delegate and then define that delegate method so the error can be reported back to you (and/or the user).

Comment: I can imagine the reasons why `startUpdatingLocation()` is disabled for the TV (unless the unit is in a moving FBI surveillance van, location is likely not to be changing often at all) and the Watch (the UI is meant to be glance or relatively quickly viewed, and the watch is tightly coupled to it's host iPhone, so we probably wouldn't want errors spewing when the Watch is periodically out of range of it's iPhone).  Would be nice if Apple's documentation team could get around to updating the docs to reflect this (ever hear of the term "1,000,000 monkeys on a million typewriters"?).

Comment: I added to didfail func like this:     func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error)
    }  and gives and optional nil error when inside the didUpdateLocations func.